# Why does the following Javascript/form not work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="hello"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert" onClick="convert(document.getElementById("inputbox"))"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function convert (text) {

    alert(text);
    return text;
</script>
```

This also does not work when I change alert to document.write.  I obviously have more HTML to go along with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious thing to me is you are nesting double quotes. Try using single quotes there.

`onClick` attribute should also be all lowercase.

I also think the way you have set it up could be improved. See below...

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="hello"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById('my-form').value = 'whatever';
}


</script>
```

You are also not closing the `function` with its ending brace.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a good idea to check the JavaScript error console in your browser. I see two errors: `convert` does not have its ending brace, and your double quotes are nested.

Comment: Bingo!  All browsers have an error console.  FF has one on the top menu>Tools>Error console.  It will usually tell you what is wrong and what line it's on.  If you wanna get deeper, try a plugin called Firebug to debug your js.

Answer (score 0):

1. quote
2. you need the text inside the textbox, not the box itself

   onClick="convert(document.getElementById('inputbox').value)"

Comment: And, also the missing brace in convert function as Hippo stated in his answer